# WebRTC Android hangup properly

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm trying to create a WebRTC app, based in [webrtc-android-codelab](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab/blob/master/Step-3/app/src/main/java/xyz/vivekc/webrtccodelab/MainActivity.java). I have a WebView and when I want to make a video call I start an activity and establish a video call, it's working but I can't hangup the video call and return to previous activity. If I close or dispose the peerconnection I get the following error:

"Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?)".

And if I call finish() in hangup() to leave the activity, the app crashes with the following error:

"E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity  This object has been released".

This is my hangup code:

```
private void hangup() {
    if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
        peerConnectionFactory.stopAecDump();
    }
    if(stream !=null) {
        while(stream.audioTracks.size() > 0) {
            AudioTrack audioTrack = stream.audioTracks.get(0);
            stream.removeTrack(audioTrack);
        }
        while(stream.videoTracks.size() > 0) {
            VideoTrack videoTrack = stream.videoTracks.get(0);
            stream.removeTrack(videoTrack);
        }
    }
    if (audioSource != null) {
        audioSource.dispose();
        audioSource = null;
    }
    if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
        try {
            videoCapturerAndroid.stopCapture();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        videoCapturerAndroid.dispose();
        videoCapturerAndroid = null;
    }
    if (videoSource != null) {
        videoSource.dispose();
        videoSource = null;
    }
    if(localPeer!=null) {
        localPeer.close();
        localPeer = null;
    }
    SignallingClient.getInstance().isInitiator=false;
    SignallingClient.getInstance().isChannelReady=false;
    SignallingClient.getInstance().isStarted=false;
}
```

Comment: This code comment https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/modules/utility/source/helpers_android.cc#95 implies it may be a problem within the library. It's not really clear to me if you are supposed to dispose the AudioTrack object or just leave them to finalize.

Answer (score 1):

It's working now with this code:

```
private void hangup() {
    try {
        localPeer.close();
        localPeer = null;
        updateVideoViews(false);
        SignallingClient.getInstance().isInitiator=false;
        SignallingClient.getInstance().isChannelReady=false;
        SignallingClient.getInstance().isStarted=false;
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```